# Known ways to modify the genetic structure of the 13 loci used in CODIS

Tags: genetics, dna, senescence

After reading the answer to [Does our DNA change during our lives?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10710/does-our-dna-change-during-our-lives), I was wondering if and how it would be possible to change the structure of the 13 loci that are used in the CODIS database, in such a way that forensic biometrics would not be able to identify/verify you anymore.

I have read about DNA chimeras, and cases exist where a bone marrow transplantation altered the DNA, depending on the sample that was taken. However, are there any other known ways to alter DNA, such as cancer, radiation, etc?

Comment: What do you think will happen, when you alter you DNA in this way? Short: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Well the nuclear plant example is of course ridiculous, but I'm wondering if cancer or aging may have an effect which is of high enough significance to circumvent DNA tests.

Comment: To cause enough mutations to make the DNA a mismatch would assuredly result in the death of the person long before the sample were obtained. The answer is still no with cancer.

Comment: @Chris I disagree that it is necessarily impossible. New techniques such as CRISPR-Cas allows for directed mutagenesis of specific loci, and if you can predict in advance the tissue they are obtaining the DNA from, it is not implausible for a modification to be carried out (for example using retroviral-induced modification).

Comment: @MarchHo In all cells of the body so that forensic biology cannot identify you? That'S impossible.

Comment: @Chris / March Ho: Any pointers to research papers about this, or do you know this from own experience?

Comment: @Michael Forensic biology works with a number of different markers which are located throughout the genome. If you want to change your genetic fingerprint, you need to change all these regions in all your cells. Otherwise you will leave a trace which makes you identifiable.

Comment: @Chris , yes I agree, so my question is if it is possible to change these (13) markers.

Comment: @Michael Depending on the source you look at, you body has something like 3,4 x 10^13 cells (or 34 trillion). See [here](http://phenomena.nationalgeographic.com/2013/10/23/how-many-cells-are-in-your-body/) for example. How do you want to change all these cells? No, that impossible.

Comment: @Chris, I edited my question. I understand that it is impossible to change them all, but cases are known where a bone marrow transplantation caused certain samples to have a different DNA than other samples, of the same body. I'm looking for other ways to accomplish that, maybe more creative, but scientifically proven.

Comment: This is important when you look at blood. A lot of forensic biology is done on lost hairs, dendruff...

Comment: So for blood it is possible, but for hairs, dendruff, saliva, etc, there are no known (proven) cases?

Comment: I have edited my question to be less opinion-based. I'm looking for scientific sources where it has been proven that it is possible to alter DNA structure of the 13 loci used in CODIS. Bone marrow transplantations are known to alter the DNA structure of the blood significantly. Blood transfusions as well, but here, the impact is temporary. In case you still feel it is too much opinion-based, I'm open for suggestions.